# The "synchronize" module does not work in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Worked on another machine with Ansible 2.9.27. It is installed on a new machine ansible [core 2.12.2].I assume that the problem is the difference in versions.

```
    [root@localhost ansible]# ansible-playbook test.yml
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'synchronize'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/root/ansible/test.yml': line 4, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
    - name: Start copy scripts
      ^ here
```

Playbook contents.

```
---
- hosts: gate_test
  tasks:
    - name: Start copy scripts
      synchronize:
        src: ~/ansible/build/base_ca
        dest: ~/
        mode: push
```

The task of the playbook, transferring a directory with contents from a local machine to a virtual one

Comment: Try ``ansible.posix.synchronize``

Comment: Yes, thank you , you've been very helpful .